# mysql 'FOR UPDATE' command not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have two php page, page1.php & page2.php

### page1.php

```
execute_query('START TRANSACTION');
$res =execute_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE');

sleep(20);

print $res->first_name;
execute_query('COMMIT');

print"\n OK";
```

### page2.php

```
 $res =execute_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1');
print $res->first_name;
```

I executing both pages almost same time

So according to the mysql 'FOR UPDATE' condition,the result in page2.php will display only after the execution of page1.php (ie after display 'OK' in page1.php), because both page reading same row.

But what is happening is,

page2.php suddenly display the result, even before completing the execution of page1.php

May i know whats wrong with ' FOR UPDATE' command.?

Comment: Considering you say "Suddenly displays the result" I would assume that page2 doesnt just load, but does wait a few moments before showing the results.

If that is the case, then my guess would be that MYSQL doesnt keep your connection open for 20seconds (your sleep) and that the lock is release when the connection is dropped.

Comment: @HugoDelsing, thanks for your comment.idon't think page2.php wait for a few moments.I tried  page2.php for  id=2 , it takes same time.

Comment: @HugoDelsing .If i add execute_query('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE'); on top of two page,then it works correctly.Don't know what exactly happening,but it get works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the table is `InnoDB` (not `MyISAM` or `MEMORY`).
You are using a `SELECT` within a transaction. I don't know your isolation level, but I guess that your transactions are not blocking each other.

See this page for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html

**EDIT:**

I'm going to explain better this concept, as requested. The isolation level is a session/global variable which determines the way the transactions are performed. Some isolation levels block other transactions when they try to modify the same row, but some isolation levels don't.

For example, if you used `UNCOMMITTED`, it doesn't block anything, because you access the actual version of the rows (which may become obsolete before the transaction ends). The other `SELECT` (page2) only reads the table, so it doesn't have to wait that the first transaction ends.

`SERIALIZABLE` is much more safe. It is not the default because it is the slowest isolation level. If you are using it, make sure that `FOR UPDATE` still makes sense for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Iam using 'InnoDB'.Can you explain  your answer related  with my example?

Comment: If i add execute_query('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE'); on top of two page,then it works correctly.Don't know what exactly happening,but it get works

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. Yes, SERIALIZABLE should be the right choice!

Answer (score -1):

I Think your `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is inside `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, so it will not lock the record until `COMMIT` statement reached , and you delayed execution with `sleep(20)`. so `page2.php` will be execute.